# What is an alternative for "the size of a pack of cigarettes"?

Tags: word-choice

Often when trying to give a reader an approximate size for something that fits in your hand that they can visualize and quickly understand, a writer might describe it as "about the size of a pack of cigarettes".

Unfortunately, many people today have a good deal of emotions attached to cigarettes and tobacco products. It is a charged word, so its use in descriptive writing may detract from the work's objective.

So what is an alternative for this old colloquialism that would be just as quickly understood? I first thought cell phone, but today's phones are quickly getting flatter and broader, while cigarette packs are closer to the cell phones of 15 years ago.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is off-topic here. Closing.

Comment: @NeilFein To be fair, I'm not asking about a specific phrase I wrote, but a common phrase that may be outdated or unwise to use in certain writing circumstances. That's really not that subjective and is likely useful to others who know the phrase (a lot of people) and do not want to use it. For example, would it be on-topic to ask about the use of the word bitch in reference to female dogs, outside of veterinary literature?

Comment: It's not about being subjective. The community has decided that it doesn't want to answer these questions. [A request to allow questions asking for rephrasing suggestions was proposed and the community voted against it.](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic/536#536) We also voted [against allowing questions asking for help generating text](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/397/should-we-be-answering-questions-about-what-to-write-about) (i.e., what to write about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pack of Playing Cards?** Some might associate this with Poker and Casinos, but it would receive a lot less heat than a pack of cigarettes I believe.

Really though, all you need to do is think of things that fit in your hand. If nothing's coming to you, take a break. Whenever you find yourself holding something in your hand, check to see if it is the proper size.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to comparing: "It fits comfortably in the hand."